# Web Page Performance Test Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, gzip

I'm using Nginx to optimize my Angular 2 project. It's added great improvements to both the security and reducing the overall size of the application.

So I'm testing my website to see where I can make improvements with webpagetest.org .

[image: web page test image]

I'm not sure what to do when it comes to Compress Images... I am serving the images from AWS S3...

Should I remove the images from the S3 bucket and put the images into an assets folder inside the angular 2 project and Gzip the entire application and serve the images from within the application?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to image serving. It can be a tricky business to make it optimally performant.

1. If you are using just a defined number of static sets. I would suggest you resize it optimally , put it on S3 and serving your images via Cloudfront instance on AWS.
2. If there are more than that. I would suggest you put in S3 and setup a real time image transformation service as thumbor.org on separate box. 
   And now configure AWS cloudfront over the thumbor service. 
   You will be to serve images with optimal size and edge caching with Cloudfront.

All of this at minimal cost.

Comment: Thanks @Bipul helpful information, I'll check it out! Cheers!